# how to deploy both x86 and x64 MSVCR120 to local application folder for C# project?

Tags: c#, .net, msvcrt, nlua

My ultimate purpose is to deploy my .NET application with clickonce and copy those runtime dlls (MSVCR, MSVCP) to my local application folder. This is needed for NLua integration into my .NET app.

That way the user doesn't need to install using Microsoft redistributable package, they do not have admin right to install that.

The possible method that I can think of now is to have both x86 and x64 dlls deployed somewhere with separate folders and during application launch, detect the user platform and copy the right dlls to actual app/bin folder. Will like to avoid doing this if some known method will work on this case.

appreciate any help given.

Comment: What's the point of having to support two versions of your app?  Just set the Platform target of your EXE project to x86 and be done with it.

Comment: the app can be memory intensive (multi millions data to be hold in memory). The default is to use x64 but some users are still running 32bits OS which is why i cannot go either 64bits or 32bits only.

Comment: That was exactly my point, it still needs to work on a 32-bit OS.  You can pretend it won't be a problem, they'll still call you for support.  If you don't want to support them then simply don't deploy 32-bit executables.

Comment: point taken. However 64bits with more addressable memory is almost unavoidable for the nature of this application. Those users who stays in 32bits OS knows that they can load less data for processing, but due to their IT support nature, they won't be moving to 64bits soon. They can still use the app, but with less data to be process at a time.

so I assume there isn't a built in way to achieve this :)